# Port JNI code to java and understand jdouble * usage

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface

I am having trouble to understand the usage of `jdouble *`. I see it used as an array and as a double. Can you explain to me what InitiateBuffer does and what the result of `State->X = State->Buffer + OFFSET_X;`?

```
#undef OFFSET_X
#define OFFSET_X 0L
#undef OFFSET_Y
#define OFFSET_Y 500L
#undef OFFSET_Z
#define OFFSET_Z 1000L

typedef struct {    
  jdoubleArray BufferArray;
  jdouble *Buffer;    
  jdouble *X;
  jdouble *Y;
  jdouble *Z;
  jint Position;
} StateStructure;

void InitiateBuffer(StateStructure *State) {
  JNIEnv *JNI = State->JNI;
  State->BufferArray = (*JNI)->NewGlobalRef(JNI,                                                      (*JNI)->NewDoubleArray(JNI, SIZE_BUFFER));
  State->Buffer = (*JNI)->GetDoubleArrayElements(JNI, State->BufferArray,  NULL);
  Fill(State->Buffer, 0, SIZE_BUFFER, FP_NAN);
  (*JNI)->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(JNI, State->BufferArray,  State->Buffer, JNI_COMMIT);
  State->TimeoutImpact = -1;
  State->TimeoutFalling = -1;
  State->Position = 0;
}

void InitiateSamples(StateStructure *State) {
  State->X = State->Buffer + OFFSET_X;
  State->Y = State->Buffer + OFFSET_Y;
  State->Z = State->Buffer + OFFSET_Z;
}

jdouble LPF(jdouble Value, jdouble *XV, jdouble *YV) {
  XV[0] = XV[1];
  XV[1] = XV[2];
  XV[2] = Value / FILTER_LPF_GAIN;
  YV[0] = YV[1];
  YV[1] = YV[2];
  YV[2] = (XV[0] + XV[2]) + 2 * XV[1] + (FILTER_FACTOR_0 * YV[0]) +    (FILTER_FACTOR_1 * YV[1]);
  return YV[2];
}

void Process() {
  jint At = State->Position;
  State->TimeoutFalling = EXPIRE(State->TimeoutFalling);
  State->TimeoutImpact = EXPIRE(State->TimeoutImpact);
  State->X_LPF[At] = LPF(State->X[At], State->XLPFXV, State->XLPFYV);
}
```

Comment: Looks like your post is mostly code. Could you add some more details?

Comment: It's a pointer to an arbitrary number of `jdouble`(s). What exactly is unclear? Are you familiar with the information covered in https://en.cppreference.com/book/pointers ?

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski can you please help me to understand what is the result of   State->X = State->Buffer + OFFSET_X;

Comment: @Michael I am not so familiar with that. I am try to translate this code to c#. Ok jdouble * is a pointer to number of doubles. What is the result of this line of code State->X = State->Buffer + OFFSET_X ?

Comment: State->Buffer = 0;

State->X[0] = 0;
State->X[1] = 1;
State->X[2] = 2;

 State->X = State->Buffer + 1500L; Which is the value of State->X ?

Comment: Why not just print the value and see for yourself? Most likely it would be 12000 (`1500 * sizeof(jdouble)`).

Comment: IMO `JNIEnv *JNI = State->JNI;` has a really bad [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).  The only legitimate ways to actually get a `JNIEnv *` are to have it passed as a parameter from the JVM in a JNI call and used under that call, or from a call to `AttachCurrentThread()`.  A `JNIEnv *` value can not be cached for later use, nor can it be used by any other thread.

Answer (score 0):

The overall architecture of what you posted attempts to partition one array into three (or more?) pieces and access them individually.

You have not shown us all of the code (like `XLPFXV` or `X_LPF`), but from what you pasted I can infer the following about `InitiateBuffer`:

- `State->BufferArray` is a new Java `double` array of size `SIZE_BUFFER`
- `State->Buffer` is a C++ friendly alias to this array
- After `InitiateBuffer`, the Java array is filled with NaN values.

`InitiateSamples` sets up three pointers within `State->Buffer`, the X pointer starts at `Buffer[0]`, the Y pointer at `Buffer[500]`, the Z pointer at `Buffer[1000]`. They can then be used to index further into the array (eg `State->Y[42]` references `State->Buffer[500+42]`).

Hope that helps.